# How to improve if I have a user-defined function in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that uses a user-defined function in the where clause to split an array into a table of values. 
it's something like this:

```
select ...
from ...
where EXISTS(SELECT Value FROM fn_Split(@Status,'#')
and EXISTS(SELECT Value FROM fn_Split(@Type,'#')
```

@Status and @Type are passed in by users. They can select multiple values to do a query.

Is there a way to remove this user-defined function? What's your suggestion?

Comment: why do you want to remove it?

Comment: What version are you on? If 2008+ you could use Table Valued Parameters instead. Probably they are only executed once anyway. You can look at "number of executions" in the properties of the actual execution plan to check this IIRC normally the plan shows the TVF population as a separate step and has a sequence operator before its actual usage.

Comment: A consultant suggeted to remove those functions. I checked the execution plan those table valued function cost 0%. I think that's not the issue on performance..

Comment: EXISTS is true if the subquery returns any rows.  Are you sure your query above does what you think it does?  As written if fn_Split() returns anything, then it's true..  Should it be an IN clause instead?   "WHERE t.col IN (SELECT Value from fn_split(@status, '#')"

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `fn_Split(@Status, '#')` and `fn_Split(@Type, '#')` do not depend on your outer query. In that case, you can call both functions before executing your query (I suppose they probably return tables), and then use those tables in your query. You can try adding indices to them if they're large.

Answer (score 0):

You can't always trust what an execution plan says, especially when it comes to scalar functions.

You can test what the effect of the scalar split function is though - take some of your typical input to those functions and do your select with it hard coded and SET STATISTICS IO/TIME ON, then do the same with the same data in the split. If the scalar is causing a problem, it should be obvious.